# Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} \right) = 0$

Tags: limits, functions, radicals

My attempt: I tried manipulating the formula, but I couldn't do anything useful. I tried to find another function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ and $f(x) \geq  \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} $ for all $x$. $f(x) = \frac1x$ fails but I *think* $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ would work (not sure how to verify this). I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: See also: [Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} \right) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216540) and [Prove that the limit of $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$ is zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1582826)

Answer (score 6):

Try multiplying your expression by $\frac{\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{x}}$ and then simplify the numerator and take the limit of this new expression as $x \to \infty$.  What do you get?

Note that this is a common method for solving a problem like this.  We say $\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{x}$ is the *conjugate* of $\sqrt{x + 1} - \sqrt{x}$.  The purpose of multiplying by this is that the numerator becomes the factored form of the difference of squares (recall: $(a + b)(a - b)= a^{2} - b^{2}$).  This gets rid of the square roots in the numerator and allows us to cancel the $x$'s.

Comment: Thanks. The new expression is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$. Is there anything left to prove, or do we just say that it's obvious that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$ approaches 0 as $x \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: @agrasin That depends if you are in a calculus class or a real analysis class.  If in a calculus class, I think it's pretty clear since $\sqrt{x + 1} + \sqrt{x}$ keeps getting bigger and bigger as $x$ gets bigger, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{ x + 1} + \sqrt{x} }$ keeps getting smaller and smaller toward $0$.  So the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

For $x\ge 0$:

$\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{x}\le \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

if and only if

$\sqrt{1+x}\le\sqrt{x}+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

if and only if

$1+x\le x+2+\dfrac{1}{x}$

if and only if

$0\le 1+\dfrac{1}{x}$

True.

Answer (score 1):

Any differentiable function $f$ satisfying $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=0$ will also satisfy $\lim_{x\to \infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))=0.$ Proof: MVT

Comment: Intuitively I can see how that's a result of the MVT. But could you tell me how to prove this? It's probably more complicated than I think because of the $\lim_{x\to\infty}$

Comment: $f(x+1)-f(x) = f'(c_x)[(x+1)-x]=f'(c_x),$ where $c_x\in (x,x+1), $ by the MVT. As $x\to \infty,c_x\to \infty \implies f'(c_x)\to 0.$

Answer (score 0):

$$
0 < \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} = \int_x^{x+1} \frac1{2\sqrt{t}}dt \le \int_x^{x+1} \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}dt = \frac1{2\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow 0
$$
We have $\frac1{2\sqrt{t}} \le \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}$ because $\frac1{2\sqrt{t}}$ is a decreasing function on the interval.

Answer (score 0):

$(x+\frac1{2x})^2
=x^2+1+\frac1{4x^2}
\gt x^2+1
$
so
$x+\frac1{2x}
\gt \sqrt{x^2+1}
$
so
$\sqrt{x^2+1}-x
\lt \frac1{2x}
$
so
$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}
\lt \frac1{2\sqrt{x}}
$.