# Evaluate: $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x})$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

> Evaluate: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} (\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x})$

I was given this problem. I'm not sure how to tackle it. $\infty-\infty$ is in indeterminate form, so I need to get it into a fraction form in order to solve. I did this by pulling an $x^2$ out of it: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}x\left(\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac2{x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac1x}\right)\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac2{x^2}}-\sqrt{\frac1x}\right)}{\frac1x}$$ Now taking the derivative: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\Large\frac{\frac{\frac{-1}{x^2}+\frac{-4}{x^3}}{2\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac2{x^2}}}-\frac{-\frac1{x^2}}{2\sqrt{\frac1x}}}{-\frac1{x^2}}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x^2\left(\frac{-1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{2\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac2{x^2}}-2\sqrt{\frac1x}}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{-x^2\left(0\right)}{2\sqrt{\frac1x+\frac2{x^2}}-2\sqrt{\frac1x}}\\=\lim_{x\to\infty}0=0$$ Since my numerator becomes zero, my entire fraction becomes zero, making zero the answer.

Is this correct? This was very messy - did I miss the easy way to do it? Is there a better way to do problems of this sort?

Comment: Your computation is NOT OK if the numerator becomes $0$ and the denominator also becomes $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar - here, my denominator also becomes zero. Does that mean my method of computation did not work?

Comment: You can have a look at: [Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} \left( \sqrt{x+1} - \sqrt{x} \right) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1216540). (Change from $x+1$ to $x+2$ does not make that much difference.)

Answer (score 9):

Hint: 
$$\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: Wow, that was simple:)

Comment: Why is this true?

Comment: $(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x})=(x+2)-x=2$

Comment: This is the usual trick which is used when we have subtraction of square roots. It reminds of the well known trick of multiplying and dividing by a complex conjugate to get rid of the imaginary part.

Comment: Called "rationalize the numerator".

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.  You could also use binomial series:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac2x}-1\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{x}\left(1+\frac1x+o\left(\frac1x\right)-1\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{\sqrt x}x=0.$$

Comment: But would he get credit for a correct answer with an incorrect method?

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\sqrt{x+2} - \sqrt{x} = \dfrac{(\sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x})(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x}} = \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x}}.$ Hence $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x+2}-\sqrt{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{1-\frac{2}{x}}+1)}=0.$

If you were looking for a nonzero answer, you could have tried something like $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x^2+x}-x$, which evaluates to $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Comment: So was I totally wrong - my answer seems to really simplify to $\frac00$?

Comment: you got the wrong denominator for the third last line.

Comment: How did I mess up?

Comment: $\dfrac{\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{4}{x^3}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}}-\frac{-\frac{1}{x^2}}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}}{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\neq \dfrac{-x^2(-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^2})}{2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}}-2\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}$